# Read and return data from text file (C#)

Tags: c#, file, text, streamreader

I'm trying to make a program that reads a text file and returns data from it (in this case, currencies). The text file has all currencies listed in this fashion:

```
USD US Dollars (USA)               1,077600 1,058100    1,097100
JPY Yen (Japan)                    133,080000   130,480000  135,680000
... etc.
```

So when a user inputs a currency code (let's say JPY), the program would print:

```
JPY Yen (Japan)                    133,080000   130,480000  135,680000
```

And after that, the program would loop and keep asking currencies until the user inputs an empty string.

This is what I have now:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

public class Currencies
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string line;

        System.IO.StreamReader currencies = new System.IO.StreamReader("currencies.txt");

        Console.Write("Enter currency code >");
        string currency = Console.ReadLine();

        while ((line = currencies.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
                if (line.Contains(currency))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(line);
                }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Now, it returns the correct line, but the loop breaks after the first input, and if you input an empty string, it returns every line of the text file.

Any ideas how to continue making this? Also, should I use ReadAllLines instead of StreamReader?

Comment: You only ask for the currency code once, so the program will only run once.   There is no way for the user to input another one because they're never given a chance to.  You need to have the prompt for a currency code in a while loop with a certain value used to end the loop (for example, -1).

Comment: Ah, right, how didn't I notice that. I'll try sticking that Console.Write inside a while loop too.

Comment: Where are you looping based on the user input rather than the currency file? That's where I think your bug is.

Comment: Also, `String.Contains` will return true if the value searched for is an empty string.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx under Return Value.

Comment: Ever do a manual check on the `line.Contains` piece where if the data is an empty string then it'll match everything for one interpretation?

Comment: You need two separate while loops.  An outer loop to prompt for user input (until the user enters a value that will exit the loop) and an inner while loop to go through the file for each input.

Comment: put the best solution in the bottom. please take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code. Explanations inline

```
public static void Main()
{
    //read all lines from file only once, and keep for future use
    var currencyDetails = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\YourDirectory\currencies.txt"); 

    string input = string.Empty;
    while (true) //keep looping until empty input by user
    {
        Console.Write("Enter currency code > ");
        input = Console.ReadLine();
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input)) //stop loop
            break;
        //from all lines of file, get the line where line starts with the user input e.g. usd
        var currencyDetail = currencyDetails.FirstOrDefault(l => l.StartsWith(input.ToUpper()));
        if (currencyDetail != null) //if a matching currency is found, show it
        {
            Console.WriteLine(currencyDetail);
        }
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

[image]

Comment: This will only grab the first line in the input. What if there are multiple lines with that currency code?

Comment: @Tim From the question statement, it looks pretty much like the one currency will be in a single line only. If OP specifies otherwise, I'll update.

Comment: This did the trick. I actually figured it out myself too after I realized it's better to use ReadAllLines (the text file ain't that big). Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

**[ReadAllLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx) vs StreamReader**

If you text file is really big, than scanning the file row by row is a good practice. In any other case to `ReadAllLines` will be a better choice, especially when scanning several times.

**Empty string returns results**

You're using the `Contains` method, which in turns search inside the string an empty string. **Every** string has inside of her an Empty string.

Solution: Test to see whatever the user entered an empty string and handle it the way you see fit.

**Input only once**

You're only searching for the input once, than it can't guess you want it to rescan again.

Solution: Make another loop, which will wrap the current loop until you need it to stop.

Comment: [`File.ReadLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx) is a nice alternative to `StreamReader`.

Answer (score 2):

this should solve it in the most effective way:

```
   public static void Main()
    {

    string line;
    bool IsEmptyString = false;
    List<string> lines = new List<string>();
    using (System.IO.StreamReader currencies = new System.IO.StreamReader("currencies.txt")
    {
        while ((line = currencies.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            lines.Add(line);
        }
    }

    while (!IsEmptyString)
    {
        string tempLine = "";
        Console.Write("Enter currency code >");
        string currency = Console.ReadLine();
        IsEmptyString = currency == "" ? true : false;
        tempLine = lines.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Contains(currency));
        if (tempLine!="")
         {
                Console.WriteLine(tempLine);
         }
        tempLine = "";

    }

}
```

Comment: This will only grab the first line in the input.  What if there are multiple lines with that currency code?

Comment: do you need all results where it contains ?

Comment: That' s a question for the OP.  I'm just pointing out a potential pitfall using `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: This solution was nice and efficient, but ultimately chose the other one after I started fiddling with ReadAllLines instead of StreamReader.